# Count Date Values of Current Month - MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, formulas

I have following date values (with time) in Column A.

```
1/1/2012 8:50  
1/1/2012 8:45  
1/1/2012 8:55  
1/1/2012 8:59  
1/1/2012 8:12  
3/1/2012 8:30  
1/1/2012 9:50  
2/1/2012 10:00
```

Now, I want to get a count of cells from Column A having date values of current Month.

I have thought of following formula, but I suspect it will work only in machines having mm-dd-yyyy as System-Date-Format.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&DATEVALUE(MONTH(TODAY())&"-1"&"-"&YEAR(TODAY())),A:A,"<"&DATEVALUE(MONTH(TODAY())+1&"-1"&"-"&YEAR(TODAY())))
```

Any workaround/trick for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use COUNTIFS for current month like this

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,A:A,"<"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)+1)`

Comment: Wow! And it will consider current month as well. Right?

Comment: Yes that will only count date values within the current month of the current year, so at the moment February 2013 - dates can contain times or not

Comment: Great Formula! And don't you think the >= and < need be interchanged in the formula?

Comment: No, formula should work as written - `EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1` gives you 1st of current month and `EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)+1` gives you 1st of next month, so formula counts any date that is >= the former and < the latter, i.e. within the current month

Comment: @barryhoudini buddy, that's brilliant - as always) my +1 as well!

Answer (score 3):

Try this: `=SUM(IF(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH(A:A),1,0))`, but press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of usual <kbd>ENTER</kbd> - this will define an ARRAY formula and will result in `{}` brackets around it (but do NOT type them manually!).

Put the formula in ANY cell you like.

Comment: Hi thank you for the correct answer. Can you please extend your formula to check for Current Year as well? I tried doing it but it always shows zero

Comment: @Tejas you mean current month AND year for the single date?

Comment: @Tejas if yes - try this: `=SUM(IF(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH(A:A),1,0)*IF(YEAR(TODAY())=YEAR(A:A),1,0))` - also an array formula.

Comment: For the `SUMPRODUCT`: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH(A:A)),--(YEAR(TODAY())=YEAR(A:A)))`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the array formula would be to use `SUMPRODUCT()`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A:A)=MONTH(TODAY())))
```

The `--` part is necessary: it turns an array of TRUE/FALSE values into numbers. The double-negative is needed to get a positive value: `=VALUE(TRUE)` gives an error, `=VALUE(-TRUE)` gives `-1`, so `=VALUE(--TRUE)` gives `+1`.

Comment: Hi thank you for the correct answer. Can you please extend your formula to check for Current Year as well? I tried doing it but it always shows zero